# Someone know a proper parameter to classify graph?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

Hi all I have 4 graph as example and I would find a parameter to classify them. The first classification can happen in base of the number of Node (so to classify the first two separate with respect to the second two) but then I have the problem that even if the first two graph are the same for me because they are both a square I am not able to find a parameter to classify them as the same graph, and so to classify the second two as two different graph, even if they have the same number of node.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1: has both an Eulerian path and a Hamiltonian path
2: has only an Eulerian path
3&4: has only an Hamiltonian path

So whether the graph has an Eulerian and/or Hamiltonian path will do most
of the classification in your definition.

To differentiate between graph 3 and 4, the only difference is that 4 has one more edge than 3 does.

Comment: I will try, but I have to write an algorithm that do it, So I have to separate also the 3 and 4 also together.